# how to install plugin for python v2.7

Tags: python, video, plugins, media

I tried to run a video DVD and it says you need to install plugin for python v2.7.
I am using Ubuntu 13.04.I am very new with ubuntu.

what codes shall i have to write to download the plugin and to install it.